# Create a border abound a HBox/Any Widget

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

**How can I create a border around a box/any widget in gtk?**

When I say border I mean the light gray rounded rectangle you see in the image below:

[image]

The functions I have attempted/looked for don't create a border, ie, set_border() creates a inner gap/padding around the widget.

```
b= gtk.VBox(False, 10)
b.set_border(1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `gtk.Frame`:

```
import gtk

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('destroy', lambda x: gtk.main_quit())
f = gtk.Frame()
b = gtk.HBox()
f.add(b)
w.add(f)
w.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

Comment: IF you're using Gtk3 you'll need to add width to the border through css, and color, and style